# What is the correct term for an HTTP/REST/Web API?

Tags: terminology

What do you call an API that is exposed via URI requests?

It seems everyone uses a different word and it makes Googling, or even skimming a page for the right API tedious.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

A web service has an API that can be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) and HTTP is the protocol used for information exchange.

This is a more modern variant of web services. Another technology before REST is using [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language), an XML based language for describing web services that used [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) for its protocol.

Yes, there are a lot of buzzwords around these concepts.